# Multiple "level" derived abstract classes with

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a problem in C++ where I have

- One abstract base class with common members and pure virtual functions. This is `A` in the code below.
- Multiple derived classes with different members and functions. This is `B` and `C` in the code below.
- Multiple derived classes that implements the virtual functions and has no new members. This is `do_stuff_1` and `do_stuff_2` in the code below.

My solution so far is to mix templates and abstract classes. The goal is to hold a pointer to the abstract classes `B` or`C` and call `do_stuff`. My questions are

1. Is my solution a good one?
2. If not, are there better solutions?
3. If so, are there some pitfalls I should be aware of?

Here is my solution so far

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

/* base virtual class */
class A {
public:
  int a;

  A(int a) : a(a) {}

  virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
};

/* concrete implementations of do_stuf */
template<class T>
class do_stuff_1 : public T {
public:
  using T::T;

  void do_stuff(){
    std::cout << "do_stuff_1 " << this->a << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class T>
class do_stuff_2 : public T {
public:
  using T::T;

  void do_stuff(){
    std::cout << "do_stuff_2 " << this->a + 1 << std::endl;
  }
};

/* derived classes from A */
class B : public A {
public:
  int b;         // one member here but many more in my application

  B(int a, int b): A(a), b(b) {}
};

class C : public A {
public:
  std::string c; // one member here but many more in my application

  C(int a, std::string c): A(a), c(c) {}
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<B> x;
  x.reset(new do_stuff_1<B>(1, 1));
  x->do_stuff();
  std::cout << x->b << std::endl;
  x.reset(new do_stuff_2<B>(1, 2));
  x->do_stuff();
  std::cout << x->b << std::endl;

  std::unique_ptr<C> z;
  z.reset(new do_stuff_1<C>(1, "Yo"));
  z->do_stuff();
  std::cout << z->c << std::endl;
  z.reset(new do_stuff_2<C>(1, "Hello"));
  z->do_stuff();
  std::cout << z->c << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
do_stuff_1 1                                                                                                                                     
1                                                                                                                                                
do_stuff_2 2                                                                                                                                     
2                                                                                                                                                
do_stuff_1 1                                                                                                                                     
Yo                                                                                                                                               
do_stuff_2 2                                                                                                                                     
Hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems fine. It's a compile time approach and you create 4 different objects.

The main drawbacks are:

- you won't know if the `do_stuff()` code is correct unless you instantiate the template.
- you could instantiate `do_stuff_1` or `do_stuff_2` with classes which are not of base class A.  You should at least use `override` in the template to make sure it overrides a virtual function.

Here a small improvement to address these issues:

```
template<class T>
class do_stuff_2 : public T {
public:
  using T::T;

  void do_stuff() override {
    static_assert (std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, "T should be derived from A");
    std::cout << "do_stuff_2 " << this->a + 1 << std::endl;
  }
};
```

By the way, using `make_unique` would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

To me looks like some kind of policy, this may look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

struct AwayToDoTheStuff {
    virtual void operator()(int a) = 0;

    virtual ~AwayToDoTheStuff() {}
};

/* concrete implementations of do_stuf */
class HowToDoStuff1 : public AwayToDoTheStuff {
    public:
        void operator()(int a) override {
            std::cout << "do_stuff_1 " << a << std::endl;
        }
};

class HowToDoStuff2 : public AwayToDoTheStuff {
    public:
        void operator()(int a) override {
            std::cout << "do_stuff_2 " << a + 1 << std::endl;
        }
};

/* base virtual class */
template <class HowToDoStuff>
class A {
    public:
        int a;

        A(int a) : a(a) {}

        void do_stuff() {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<AwayToDoTheStuff, HowToDoStuff>::value);
            HowToDoStuff()(a);
        }
};

/* derived classes from A */
template <class HowToDoStuff>
class B : public A<HowToDoStuff> {
    public:
        int b;         // one member here but many more in my application

        B(int a, int b): A<HowToDoStuff>(a), b(b) {}
};

template <class HowToDoStuff>
class C : public A<HowToDoStuff> {
    public:
        std::string c; // one member here but many more in my application

        C(int a, std::string c): A<HowToDoStuff>(a), c(c) {}
};

int main() {
    B<HowToDoStuff1>(1, 1).do_stuff();
    B<HowToDoStuff2>(1, 2).do_stuff();

    C<HowToDoStuff1>(1, "Yo").do_stuff();
    C<HowToDoStuff2>(1, "Hello").do_stuff();

    return 0;
}
```

but I must say this is quite hard to tell if a solution match well with an example that much generic. I hope it will help you in some ways...

**EDIT**:

You seem to *need* to have a common base class so that you can pass your objects B and C to a common function of the kind `void f(A &a);`

Then my example can be adapted that way:

```
/* base virtual class */
class A {
    public:
        void do_stuff() = 0;
};

template <class HowToDoStuff>
class Policy_A : public A {
    public:
        int a;

        A(int a) : a(a) {}

        void do_stuff() override {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<AwayToDoTheStuff, HowToDoStuff>::value);
            HowToDoStuff()(a);
        }
};

/* derived classes from A */
template <class HowToDoStuff>
class B : public Policy_A<HowToDoStuff> {
    public:
        int b;         // one member here but many more in my application

        B(int a, int b): Policy_A<HowToDoStuff>(a), b(b) {}
};

template <class HowToDoStuff>
class C : public Policy_A<HowToDoStuff> {
    public:
        std::string c; // one member here but many more in my application

        C(int a, std::string c): Policy_A<HowToDoStuff>(a), c(c) {}
};
```

So that the do_stuff can be called on opaque A objects.

You may also pass the HowToDoStuff object at creation:

```
/* base virtual class */
class A {
    std::unique_ptr<AwayToDoTheStuff> _stuffer;
    public:
        int a;

        A(std::unique_ptr<AwayToDoTheStuff> stuffer, int a) : _stuffer(std::move(stuffer)), a(a) {}

        void do_stuff() {
            (*_stuffer)(a);
        }
};

/* derived classes from A */
class B : public A {
    public:
        int b;         // one member here but many more in my application

        B(std::unique_ptr<AwayToDoTheStuff> &stuffer, int a, int b): A(std::move(stuffer), a), b(b) {}
};

class C : public A {
    public:
        std::string c; // one member here but many more in my application

        C(std::unique_ptr<AwayToDoTheStuff> &stuffer, int a, std::string c): A(std::move(stuffer), a), c(c) {}
};

int main() {

    auto stuffer1forB = std::unique_ptr<AwayToDoTheStuff>(new HowToDoStuff1);
    auto stuffer2forB = std::unique_ptr<AwayToDoTheStuff>(new HowToDoStuff2);

    B(stuffer1forB, 1, 1).do_stuff();
    B(stuffer2forB, 1, 2).do_stuff();

    auto stuffer1forC = std::unique_ptr<AwayToDoTheStuff>(new HowToDoStuff1);
    auto stuffer2forC = std::unique_ptr<AwayToDoTheStuff>(new HowToDoStuff2);

    C(stuffer1forC, 1, "Yo").do_stuff();
    C(stuffer2forC, 1, "Hello").do_stuff();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An issue with this solution is that I cannot make a pointer to class `B` or `C`. E.g., I cannot have a function like `void f(B &b)`. Thus, I cannot achieve the following goal:_" The goal is to hold a pointer to the abstract classes ..."_ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point; I removed the unique_ptr here as I thought they were not essential to the hierachy of classes, but you can still create pointer to B and C if you wish.

Comment: They are templates so I would need to have template functions or multiple function with argument like e.g., `void f(B<HowToDoStuff1> &b)` and `void f(B<HowToDoStuff2> &b)`. I might be wrong.